# Redis high speed requirement

Tags: redis

I have a specific requirement where 50 clients will update some 10K keys.
Each client need to INCR on all 10K keys.
Since the rate at which each key may get incremented is 1000/sec, I want to share the load across different Redis Servers.
And Each client when they do next INCR/GET, they should get latest value that is present in master/slave.
I tried one master and one slave, and slave configured with write permission. But if I INCR a key in slave, it is not getting reflected in master.
Hence I'm not able to use both master and slave for INCR operations.
Is there some other option where I can configure master<->master and Redis will take care of sync-ing the data in every 10 milli sec or less?

Comment: "if I INCR a key in slave, it is not getting reflected in master" - of course. You might have a wrong idea about what master-slave replication actually does.

Comment: Isn't redis cluster production-ready by now?

Comment: @Sergio yes it is :)